# How to put repeating buttons in a template without losing functionality

Tags: mvvm, command, datatemplate

In a project (Prism, MVVM, Windows8.1 StoreApp) I have a piece of XAML like this:

```
                <GridView 
                x:Name="grvLetters" 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                Margin="80,0,0,0" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Button x:Name="btnA" 
                    Content="A" 
                    Command="{Binding Letter_Clicked}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btnA, Path=Content}"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnB" 
                    Content="B" 
                    Command="{Binding Letter_Clicked}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btnB, Path=Content}"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnC" 
                    Content="C" 
                    Command="{Binding Letter_Clicked}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btnC, Path=Content}"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnD" 
                    Content="D" 
                    Command="{Binding Letter_Clicked}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btnD, Path=Content}"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnE" 
                    Content="E" 
                    Command="{Binding Letter_Clicked}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btnE, Path=Content}"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnF" 
                    Content="F" 
                    Command="{Binding Letter_Clicked}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btnF, Path=Content}"/>
            </GridView>
```

I would like to put this in a DataTemplate, but when I do that, the command is not forwarded to the ViewModel. Here's what I have been trying so far:

This is what I have in the template (based on the below suggestion of Daniel Sklenitzka):

```
     <DataTemplate  x:Key="LetterButton">
        <Button 
            x:Name="btnLetter" 
            Command="{Binding Letter_Clicked}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=grvLetters, Path=Content}"
            />
    </DataTemplate>
```

That suggestion does not work, so I have changed back to:

```
    <DataTemplate  x:Key="LetterButton">
        <Button 
            x:Name="btnLetter" 
            Command="{Binding Letter_Clicked}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btnLetter, Path=Content}"
            />
    </DataTemplate>
```

In order to have the ItemsSource for the GridView I have added this in the ViewModel:

```
        Public Property Alfabet As String() = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}
```

The XAML for the GridView has been changed into:

```
 <GridView 
                x:Name="grvLetters"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Alfabet}"
                Grid.Row="1" 
                Margin="80,0,0,0" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource LetterButton}}" 
                >
```

Unfortunately this won't work. The letters appear perfectly on the View, but there is no reaction in the ViewModel when a button is clicked.

The buttonclick would have to be caught in the viewmodel (this is not the problem, the command is received in the ViewModel when I use the first XAML above.

But how to improve this approach? Any suggestions ? More than welcome.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

When you use an ItemsSource and DataTemplates, the container (GridView in your case) creates an instance of the template for every element in the ItemsSource collection, and it sets the element as the DataContext of this instance.

That means that the DataContext of your Button is a letter, and the letter doesn't have a property Letter_Clicked, which is why the binding fails.

Try binding the command like this:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.Letter_Clicked, ElementName=grvLetters}"
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply, but I'm afraid I dont fully understand the code you provide.

When I have the DataTemplate in the Page.Resources, then it's not possible to refer to grvLetters, only to the btnLetter. Next, you suggest a change in binding of the command, but Command cannot be bound to DataContext. In Prism MVVM the Command is binding to a commandDelegate in the ViewModel. What you suggest would mean that the commandDelegate's name would have to change. I will try further, your explanation of the details of DataTemplates is clear enough. 

Bye

Comment: The Binding is resolved at runtime, so it can refer to grvLetters, because the instantiated template is in the same visual tree as the GridView.

As for the command: You don't need to change anything. The binding as defined in my answer is resolved like this:
First the element with name grvLetters is resolved, resulting in your GridView. Then the DataContext property of this element is resolved, resulting in the same object that the bindings in your original example refer to (the ViewModel defining your Command). And eventually the Letter_Clicked property of the ViewModel is resolved.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but it won't work, whereas the implementation with the repeating buttons like in the first code snippet keeps working correctly. On the same page that is! I have updated the Original question to show the code as it is now.

Comment: What I can add to this is the error message that results from the change in the code. It says: _Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Content' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridView'. BindingExpression: Path='Content' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridView'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' (Name='btnLetter'); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')._ It doesn't surprise me, because the content is part of the Button, and nof part ot the GridView. So unfortunately your suggestion is for the worse...

Comment: Please read again, the code you posted above is not what I suggested. Try this:

<DataTemplate x:Key="LetterButton">
    <Button x:Name="btnLetter" 
            Command="{Binding DataContext.Letter_Clicked, ElementName=grvLetters}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
            Content="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I have tried literaly would you suggest in your last posting, but it doen not improve. I think the Command binding cannot be changed like you suggest, because it must have the name of the DelegateCommand in the ViewModel. And binding the Content would have the reverse effect: the button would react on changes in the ViewModel. The CommandParameter should be bound to the Button itself, passing through the Content of the Button. NB! The original XAML with the repeating buttons still works with that implementation, on the same View!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really trying to accomplish, but I tried it myself and it worked fine.
Using just {Binding} for the parameter will result in the letter itself being passed to the command.